# Django-cms with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, django-cms

I've got following problem with mod_wsgi and Django-CMS.

Here is my httpd.conf fragment:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module               /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so    
WSGIScriptAlias /cms /home/user/apps/django_cms/django_cms/site.wsgi
```

When I'm opening my server_IP/cms it redirects me to server_IP/pl/cms/ and returns 404 error. Polish is the only language, can I avoid redirecting or change it to /cms/pl instead of /pl/cms?
Here is my site.wsgi:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/apps/')
sys.path.append('/home/user/apps/django_cms/')
sys.path.append('/home/user/apps/django_cms/django_cms/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py file, try commenting out:

```
#LANGUAGES = [
#    ('pl', 'Polish'),
#]
```

Make sure your httpd.conf file has a directory section:

```
<Directory "/home/user/apps/django_cms">
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
  SetHandler wsgi-script
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In your site.wsgi file, replace:

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

with:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Now I'm geting error: " configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /cms", here's my httpd.conf: http://dpaste.com/hold/1287859/

Comment: It worked for me, I didn't have to do anything else for the site.wsgi